# Integral of Wiener process $\int_{0}^t e^{\lambda u } dZ_u$

Tags: integration, stochastic-integrals

I am not quite sure how to solve this integral to be able to plot it and do numerical calculations with it. $\lambda$ is a known constant, $u$ is time, and $Z_u$ is a wiener process. Can anyone provide some direction on how to solve it please?

$f = \int_{0}^t e^{\lambda u } dZ_u$

Comment: If you want just to sample the terminal value you can use the fact that as a wiener integral $\int_0^t e^{\lambda u } dZ_u$ is a mean zero normal random variable with variance $\int_0^t e^{2\lambda u} du$. If you want to sample the trajectory of $\int_0^t e^{\lambda u} dZ_u$ you can use an Euler-Maruyama or Milstein scheme or you can use integration by parts to write the wiener integral as $$\int_0^t e^{\lambda u} dZ_u = e^{\lambda t} Z_t - \lambda\int_0^t e^{\lambda u} Z_u du$$ and discretize the right-hand side.